# Mac - Alias linking breaks after unzipping the folder

Tags: mac, compression, disk-image

I am new to Mac.
I am trying to zip a folder in which there are two sub folders say folder A and folder B.
I create an Alias of a file in folder B and move the Alias to folder A.

After I create a zip file and then unzip it, the link breaks.

I am using Archive Utility for zipping/unzipping.

Answer (score 0):

The alias will still point to the location of the original file, not the new unzipped location.

I'm sure there must be a smarter workaround than this - but this works…

- Open Disk Utility
- File Menu > New Image > Image from Folder
- Select the folder you wish to be able to distribute.
- In the Save dialog, save using the Image Format : read/write option
- Mount the newly-created Disk Image in Finder.
- Delete existing aliases & replace with new ones created inside the Disk Image
- When finished, Eject the mounted Disk Image.
- Back in Disk Utility - Images > Convert…
- Select your Disk Image & Save as Image Format : Compressed

You now have a fully-portable compressed archive, which will never lose the Aliases.